# Difference between django mongoengine vs mongoengine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

What's the difference between django mongoengine and mongoengine
Can i use django default/build-in form mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Django-mongoengine** is a django extension that provides integration with MongoEngine. It is basically like other django-extensions which provides added features.

But **MongoEngine** is a `Document-Object Mapper` (think **ORM**, but for document databases) for working with MongoDB from Python. 
As it uses a simple declarative API, similar to the Django ORM, `Django-mongoengine` make it work with django. But it is exclusively for working with mongodb using python.

> Note

If you use **only mongodb** then, you **can't use admin functionality** of Django. You can try using django-non rel. But I will not suggest to go with that. Coz it works with Django-1.3 which is quite old.

If you want to use the admin functionality also and mongodb also then you can use 2 databases first the relational one for admin functionality and then mongodb for other purposes.

Comment: so i can't use djagno admin/auth/form while using MongoEngine ?

Comment: No, you cant use admin functionality then. You can try using django-non rel. But I will not suggest to go with that. Coz it works with Django-1.3 which is quite old.

Comment: If you want to use the admin functionality also and mongodb also then you can use 2 databases first the relational one for admin functionality and then mongodb for other purposes.

Comment: wow is it possible to use mysql-djanog in one project.  How would the settings.py file look like then. And i have to use django_mongoengine or MongoEngine ?

Comment: Yeah it is possible.

Comment: How would the settings.py file look like then. And i have to use django_mongoengine or MongoEngine ?

Comment: In `settings.py` add `from mongoengine import connect` at top. Then keep your default database you can add another database. But explaining everything here is out of scope. You can search on how to use mongodb in django using mongoengine. Hope it helps you. And please select my answer if it was helpful for you. Thanks for cooperation.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for you help